# Trim the contents of a String array in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, trim

```
    String []lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (String line in lines)
    {
        line.Trim();
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `String.Trim` returns the Trimmed version as a new String. And you can't do `line = line.Trim()`. So is the only way to do this an old-school `for` loop?

```
    for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;++i)
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Trim();
    }
```

**Note** I am restricted to Visual Studio 2005 i.e. .Net 2.0

Comment: Are you asking how to make it better?

Comment: Question is `Is the only way to do this an old-school for loop?` You can't see it?

Comment: I totally didn't see `is` :D

Comment: No, the for loop is not the only way, but it's probably the best way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lines.Select(l => l.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, for .NET 2.0:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetTrimmed(IEnumerable<string> array)
{
    foreach (var s in array)
        yield return s.Trim();
}
```

Used through:

```
lines = new List<string>(GetTrimmed(lines)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I missed the possibly crucial .NET 2 tag initially; all this lambda stuff isn't available is it?

Comment: I have added an example of usage in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Eve, I added my answer with `List<string>` before this edit. :-)

Comment: it seems to me that the for loop in the question is simpler and cleaner (less GC pressure) than the approach offered here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), we have `List<string>` in .NET 2.0.

So, try with `List<string>`.

```
String []lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

List<string> yourLinesTrimed = new List<string>;
foreach (String line in lines)
{
        yourLinesTrimed.Add(line.Trim());
}
```

Then you can convert the `List<string>` in an array, using `ToArray()`.

Let's build a method that does this:

```
 public String[] TrimAnArray(String[] lines)
 {
     List<string> yourLinesTrimed = new List<string>;
     foreach (String line in lines)
     {
         yourLinesTrimed.Add(line.Trim());
     }
     return yourLinesTrimed.ToArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

*"So is the only way to do this an old-school for loop?"* Yes, on .NET 2  you have no Linq stuff. But to be honest, the  "old-school for loop" is also the most efficient, most readable and shortest approach. So what's the problem?

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    lines[i] = lines[i].Trim();
```

Comment: it's not a problem, simply a quest for knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You could also use LINQ:

```
String []lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
                .Select(line => line.Trim())
                .ToArray();
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you are limited to .NET 2.0, then I would stick with the for-loop as you have done in your second code sample. I don't think there are much better ways of doing it, a for-loop is efficient enough. There are of course some workarounds for making LINQ work in .NET 2.0, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: @John Oh, sorry, missed that it is .net 2.0 you are using. But there are workarounds to use LINQ in .Net 2.0, but I'd rather use the for-loop.

Comment: .NET 2.0 doesn't support LINQ queries.